# Completeness of metric space defined by a continuous bijection?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Suppose $f: X \to Y$ is a continuous bijection.Given a metric $d$ on $X$ we can define a metric $e$ on $Y$ as: $e(y_1,y_2)= d(f^{-1}(y_1),f^{-}(y_2))$.

$1$. Suppose $(X,d)$ is complete,does this implies that $(Y,e)$ is complete ?

$2$ Similarly given a metric on $Y$ we can define a metric on $X$ in obvious way.
  Suppose $(Y,e)$ is complete,does this implies that $(X,d)$ is complete ?

Comment: Definition of $e$ makes $f$ an isometry. Question 1 should really be just a definition chasing, assume a sequence $y_n$ is Cauchy, and show that it is convergent using the relationship between them and $f^{-1}(y_n)$. 2 is obvious by symmetry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f: (X,d) \rightarrow (Y,e)$ is an isometry: $e(f(x), f(y)) = d(x,y)$ by construction.

If $(y_n)$ is Cauchy in $(Y,e)$, then $(f^{-1}(y_n))$ is Cauchy in $(X,d)$ so ...

Fror the second, define $d(x,y) = e(f(x), f(y))$. Again we that $f$ is an isometry.

If $(x_n)$ is $d$-Cauchy, so $f(x_n)$ is $e$-Cauchy, so ...